# show back to school call out only on homepage in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to show back to school call out only on homepage in magento and no need to display on all other pages
i tried with commenting this but its removing in home page also

```
<block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
      <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>
      <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>
</block>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

by default the xml markup you mentioned is added in the `<default>` layout handle. This makes it appear on all pages.
You need to remove it from there and add it inside the `<cms_index_index>` handle.
So remove the code you mentioned and add this in any layout file right under the `<layout>` tag.

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
            <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>
            <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```